# MaskedTextBox positioning issue - WP7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm creating the MaskedTextBox in WP7.1 In that i want to select all text in the first click. in the second click,caret position should be the clicked position. But caret position always going at the starting or ending positions wherever i clicked inside the MaskedTextBox.

Please anyone help me to fix this issue.

> protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
>
> ```
>     { 
>         if (IsFirstClickSelect)
>
>             this.SelectAll();       
>
>         base.OnGotFocus(e);
>     }
> ```

For the first click, text is focused and selected all text inside got focus method. for the second click we could not catch he GotFocus method because it is already focussed. So Please tell me to set the clicked position.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the **default behaviour** of TextBox in Windows Phone 7.1